# comparar variable con array asociativo en ciclo en php

Tags: php, array, api, arraylist, webapi

hola a todos tengo una variable y variable con array asociativo algo asi

"España"=>"Madrid",
"Francia"=>"París", 
"Inglaterra"=>"Londres", 
"Italia"=>"Roma", 
"Portugal"=>"Lisboa", 
"Alemania"=>"Berlín"

y una variable $pais = 'España';

y tengo un ciclo foreach

```html
$response_array = json_decode($response, true);
 foreach ($response_array as $value) {
   $cadena = "El nombre es: '". $value['pais'] ."', y su capital es: ". $value['capital'] ."},";
   print ($cadena);
 }
```

y lo que quiero es que al buscar el país solo me devuelva la información del país que estoy seleccionando en la variable

Answer (score 0):

Tu script funcionaría si la estructura fuera:

```
$response_array = [
    ['pais' => 'España', 'capital' => 'Madrid'],
    ['pais' => 'Inglaterra', 'capital' => 'Londres'],
];
```

Sin embargo, tu array está en la forma `'País' => 'Capital'` y, para que funcione, solo necesitas recorrer por clave y valor:

```
$response_array = ["España"=>"Madrid", "Francia"=>"París", "Inglaterra"=>"Londres", "Italia"=>"Roma", "Portugal"=>"Lisboa", "Alemania"=>"Berlín"];
// Creas la variable para buscar país
$pais = 'España';
// Declara la variable para capital
$capital = '';
foreach($response_array as $clave => $valor) {
    // Comparas si la clave corresponde al país
    if($pais == $clave) {
        $capital = $valor;
        // No es necesario continuar recorriendo, hay que salir
        break;
    }
}
$cadena = "El nombre es: '$pais', y su capital es: '$capital'";
```